# Finding contours of a two-part letter

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, opencv3.0

Suppose that I have an image of letters and I want to find the region of those letters.

[image]

I have wrote this code:

```
MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 10   
img = cv2.imread("alphabets.png")     
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
blured = cv2.blur(gray, (5,5), 0)    
img_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blured, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
imgContours, Contours, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in Contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > MIN_CONTOUR_AREA:
        [X, Y, W, H] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (X, Y), (X + W, Y + H), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imshow('contour', img)
```

But the code above has this output:
**result**

[image]

What can I do to find contour for letters that are not continuous like 'i' or Arabic letters?

Comment: You can try to categorize the dots and the base from the letters (using your alreay implemented threshold), and assign every found dot to its closest base contour. You then need to draw a bounding rect arround the base contour and the found dots

Comment: @DarthCoder checkout the answer it is much simpler

Answer (score 7):

Before finding the contours, you can use some segmentation methods:

```
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30, 10))
threshed = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rect_kernel)
```

[image]

and after applying `cv2.findContours` the result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: like the notion of using a non-square kernel !!

Comment: @M.Mehranian
Your welcome! So you can approve the answer ;)
thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem. I fix it to this way.
add this code :

`dst = cv2.Canny(gray, 0, 150)`

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
  dst = cv2.Canny(gray, 0, 150)
blured = cv2.blur(dst, (5,5), 0)    
img_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blured, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
imgContours, Contours, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in Contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > MIN_CONTOUR_AREA:
        [X, Y, W, H] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (X, Y), (X + W, Y + H), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imshow('contour', img)
```